# jQuery Mobile: can't enter a space in input

Tags: jquery, mobile

Greetings,

I have the following jQuery mobile page:

Everything works fine, except I can't press space to enter a space! It just ignores my spacebar.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: If you hold down your space bar it works... But you really should debug your code first and reduce the possibilties to a human limit. 1000+ Lines of not commented and not documented code are very awefull to read. Give us a function or piece of code and you may have luck that someone could help you.

Comment: Yes, holding down space bar seems to work! I think the space bar on the mobile should work?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In certain situations (in lists for example), jquery mobile grabs the space bar key (and the enter key) to trigger navigation actions.

If you have an input text in a list, then you won't get the space and enter events.

My solution is dirty but it works. Before calling initializePage, change the code of the SPACE bar in jquerymobile internals. The consequence is that you won't get the navigation actions with the spacebar but you still have them with the enter key.

```
$.mobile.keyCode.SPACE=13; //to avoid spacebar problem, make jquerymobile think that the sapcebar code is 13 (enter)
$.mobile.initializePage();
```